# .command files throws "unknown path" error

Tags: linux, shell, command

I
i have renamed my .sh file to .command to make it execute on doubleclick.

```
cp -avRi "./source/" "./destination"
```

But now I am getting an "unknown path" error. Do i have to add the current path somehow?

Comment: I would guess that double-clicked scripts get run in your `${HOME}` directory, so writing them to use relative paths is likely to be problematic unless you take that into account.

Comment: So what do you suggest? How can i get the current dir?

Answer (score 0):

That worked

```
CWD="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```